# Comments column has been added to document library, and comments exist but Comments column is blank. Why?

Tags: 2013, column, comments

In SharePoint 2013, I have added the Comments column to my Shared Documents library. Several of the documents have version comments that were entered at check in, but the comments are not showing up in the Comments column. It is completely blank, and I can't figure out why.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Comments" is a comment on the document itself and "Check In Comment" is a comment left as part of the check-out/check-in process (version control).  You cannot see the version comments ("Check In Comment") because you are not displaying them; instead, you have errantly chosen to display the document comments.

Modify the view, unchecking "Comments", and instead checking "Check In Comment".

Comment: Thank you both (Gintas K and C Strabala) very much! I knew it would be something simple because I had done it before on another job. I was just looking in the wrong place. You guys are the best! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your "Comments" column is not necessary.

To display Version Comments in the Library:

1. Modify the View
2. Add "Check In Comment" property to the View